# PHP Nusoap Session

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, session, nusoap

```
require_once('soap/nusoap.php');

$soap = new soap_server();

$soap->configureWSDL('ClientSecurityService','http://localhost/sec/webservices/');
$soap->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://www.soapinterop.org/xsd/'; 


$soap->register(
    'user_authentication',
    array(
        'apikey'            =>'xsd:string',
        'scretekey'         =>'xsd:string',
        'emailaddress'      =>'xsd:string',
        'password'          =>'xsd:string',
        ),  
    array('message'=>'xsd:string'),
    'http://soapinterop.org'
);  

$soap->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');  

function user_register($apikey='', $scretekey='', $username='', $emailaddress='', $password='', $first_name='', $last_name='', $date_of_birth='', $user_ip=''){

    if(API_class::check_credentials($apikey, $scretekey) == true){

        $error                          = '';
        $validation                     = new Validation_class();
        $validation->validate[]         = $emailaddress . '|Email address |req|email';
        $validation->validate[]         = $password . '|Password |req';
        $validation->validate[]         = $first_name . '|First name |req';
        $validation->validate[]         = $last_name . '|Last name |req';

        $error                          = $validation->validation('p');
        if($error == ''){
            $new_user                   = new User_class();
            $new_user->uname            = $username;
            $new_user->email_address    = $emailaddress;
            $new_user->hashed_password  = md5($password);
            $new_user->fname            = $first_name;
            $new_user->lname            = $last_name;
            $new_user->date_of_birth    = $date_of_birth;
            $new_user->user_ip          = $user_ip;
            $new_user->save();

            $message = 'User created successfully';

        } else {
            $message = $error;  
        }


    } else {
        $message = 'Invalid API Reference.';    
    }
    return $message; 
}






function user_authentication($apikey='', $scretekey='', $emailaddress='', $password=''){


    if(API_class::check_credentials($apikey, $scretekey) == true){

        $error                          = '';
        $validation                     = new Validation_class();
        $validation->validate[]         = $emailaddress . '|Email address |req|email';
        $validation->validate[]         = $password . '|Password |req';

        $error                          = $validation->validation('p');
        if($error == ''){
            //$password = md
            $user_login = User_class::user_authentication($emailaddress,$password);

            if($user_login != false){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_login->user_id;
                $message = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            } else {
                $message = 'Invalid login information.';
            }

        } else {
            $message = $error;  
        }


    } else {
        $message = 'Invalid API Reference.';    
    }
    return $message; 
}
```

I am trying to geenrate a web service, which can provide users the ability to login, but, I want to register the session on providers site, all code is working fine, in responce it shows the session ID, but when I access a page of provider site and try to PRINT that SESSION, it shows empty.

Can anyone help me why this code is not registering session on WebService Provider website?

Comment: Did you already fixed it?

Comment: Can you please post the solution? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: The above is working 100% correct, I was testing in wrong way, above code is correct

Comment: I'm going to do it in a different way, using a .NET webservice. I think that will work better for my problem. I have a .NET service and a PHP client and the webservice need to be online 24/7. I can't accomplish that with NuSOAP.

Comment: Hello Kam 
yes it set session on server on 1st time call but in 2nd time call if you check user already login or not using session instead of calling  user_authentication function than it does not work because  on second time call 1st time settled Session was reset.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working, fine if anyone have same problem can use, I was testing in wrong way, it was my bad :D